# Tfilat ha-Derekh "ותחזירנו לשלום"

Tags: time, nuschaot, tefilat-haderech

In Tfilat ha-Derekh there are optional words "ותחזירנו לשלום". When do we add these? Sometimes it is written "if somebody means to return immediately say also..." and sometimes I've seen "at the same day" instead of immediately.

What of above is correct?

Comment: Note some say "_v'sachazirenu l'vesenu l'shalom_".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/289446/jewish/About-Tefilas-Haderech.htm) where the answer to your question appears to be "both".

> Regarding adding a special request for a safe return trip, a great number of the sidurim that the author has perused have no such
>   insertion.
>
> In sidurim following Nusach Chabad there is a parenthetical statement
>   that if one is planning on returning right away he should insert the
>   words “vesachazireinu leshalom” (ותחזירנו לשלום) — “and return us in
>   peace.” Thus, he would recite the Tefilas Haderech just once, on the
>   way there. However, on longer trips, it appears that these two words
>   are not said .
>
> “Returning immediately” means before the next morning.
>
> However, according to HaRav Betzalel Stern, the words “vesachazireinu
>   leshalom” should always be inserted when one has intention of
>   returning home, even if it will be after a long absence, such as a
>   prolonged business trip, vacation, and the like. If, however, one is
>   making a one-way, long distance move and is not returning, these two
>   words are not added.

Of course other nuschaot have ותחזירנו לשלום.

A similar approach can be found [here](http://www.dinonline.org/2012/05/31/halacha-talk-tefilas-haderech/). It says:

> Another phrase in tefilas haderech over which there is a disagreement
>   is,  “return us to our homes in
>   peace.” Some are of the opinion that it is unnecessary to specify this
>   as it is included in the phrase, “and cause us to reach our desired
>   destination,” while others include these words in the text. The
>   prevalent custom is to include this phrase if one intends to return
>   home that day. (Sefer Ishei Yisrael 50:2, footnote 3)

This "prevalent custom" fits with what I have been taught that the validity of a Tefilas Haderech is only up to the next morning and so there is no need to say ותחזירנו לשלום if you stay longer.